# Numpy array - stack multiple columns into one using reshape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

For a 2D array like this:

`table = np.array([[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33],[41,42,43]])`

Is it possible to use `np.reshape` on `table` to get an array `single_column` where each column of `table` is stacked vertically? This can be accomplished by splitting `table` and combining with `vstack`.

```
single_column = np.vstack(np.hsplit(table , table .shape[1]))
```

Reshape can combine all the rows into a single row, I'm wondering if it can combine the columns as well to make the code cleaner and possibly faster.

```
single_row = table.reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose first, then reshape:

```
table.T.reshape(-1, 1)

array([[11],
       [21],
       [31],
       [41],
       [12],
       [22],
       [32],
       [42],
       [13],
       [23],
       [33],
       [43]])
```

Comment: This is much more concise than my hasty realization.

Answer (score 1):

A few more approaches are:

- 1) [flattening using Fotran order](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), followed by explicit *promotion* as a column vector
- 2) [reshaping using Fortran order](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), followed by explicit *promotion* as a column vector

---

```
# using approach 1
In [200]: table.flatten(order='F')[:, np.newaxis]
Out[200]: 
array([[11],
       [21],
       [31],
       [41],
       [12],
       [22],
       [32],
       [42],
       [13],
       [23],
       [33],
       [43]])

# using approach 2
In [202]: table.reshape(table.size, order='F')[:, np.newaxis]
Out[202]: 
array([[11],
       [21],
       [31],
       [41],
       [12],
       [22],
       [32],
       [42],
       [13],
       [23],
       [33],
       [43]])
```