# Numpy array - stack multiple columns at the end of an array as rows using reshape

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I want to stack `n` number of columns as new rows at the end of the array. I was trying to do it with reshape but I couldn't make it. For example given the table

```
table = np.array([[11,12,13,14,15,16],
                  [21,22,23,24,25,26],
                  [31,32,33,34,35,36],
                  [41,42,43,44,45,46]])
```

my output if `n=2` should be:

```
array([[11, 12], 
       [21, 22], 
       [31, 32], 
       [41, 42], 
       [13, 14], 
       [23, 24], 
       [33, 34], 
       [43, 44], 
       [15, 16], 
       [25, 26], 
       [35, 36], 
       [45, 46]])
```

and if `n=3`:

```
array([[11, 12, 13], 
       [21, 22, 23], 
       [31, 32, 33], 
       [41, 42, 43], 
       [14, 15, 16], 
       [24, 25. 26], 
       [34, 35, 36], 
       [44, 45, 46]])
```

---

Update:

Ok,I managed to achieve the result that I want with the following command:

```
import numpy as np

n=2
np.concatenate(np.split(table, table.shape[1]/n, axis=1), axis=0)
n=3
np.concatenate(np.split(table, table.shape[1]/n, axis=1), axis=0)
```

I do not know though if it is possible to be done with reshape.

Comment: The best way to answer if `arr1` can be reshaped into `arr2` is to  check if `arr1.flatten()` is equal to `arr2.flatten()`. Clearly not in your case. So if you expect to use a single `reshape(...)` method, you'll need to use additionally something else (it might be double usage of `reshape(..)` in some scenarios)

Comment: Well in the beginning I was trying to figure out whether I could use the solutions from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444777/numpy-array-stack-multiple-columns-into-one-using-reshape where they also use `flatten()` but apparently as you mention most likely it is not possible.

Comment: Well, at least you can apply some additional methods such as `np.transpose`, `np.squeeze`, `np.swapaxis`. You'll check also a nice example of [`maxpooling`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463514/3044825) which is quite close to your problem. I'll try to adapt it to your problem.

Comment: Instead of using concatenate you could use np.row_stack: np.row_stack(np.split(table, table.shape[1]/n, axis=1)).  Admittedly, the only benefit of this is no need to specify axis.  It's just one more potential avenue to use.  Personally, I see no compelling need to use reshape here, what you have is fine.

Comment: Yup, most likely you are right. The point was that I've related it to `reshape` because that was the first command that it came to my mind to use but as you say what I have is likely good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP offers a solution:

```
np.concatenate(np.split(table, table.shape[1]/n, axis=1), axis=0)
```

It appears to be inefficient because `np.split` forces to change data to list of arrays and then iterate it within outer argument. More over `np.concatenate` is not that efficient as well. They are ideal to work when lengths of items of list are not balanced.

My solution is like so:

```
np.vstack(table.reshape(4,3,2).swapaxes(0,1))
#np.vstack(table.reshape(4,2,3).swapaxes(0,1)) #for second case
```

Let's check if my prediction of performance was correct:

```
%timeit np.vstack(table.reshape(4,3,2).swapaxes(0,1))
%timeit np.concatenate(np.split(table, table.shape[1]/2, axis=1), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
22.4 µs ± 2.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
42.8 µs ± 9.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I was looking for solution with an assist of [`numpyviz`](https://github.com/loijord/numpyviz) (Disclaimer: I'm its author). There is a `numpyviz`ualisation that helps to understand a process better:

[image]

In general you need to set a shape so that blocks preserves width and height. `Numpyviz`ualisation hints that `axis=0` and `axis=2` of new shape corresponds to `table.shape[0]` and `n` respectively. Also the lenght of middle axis is a number of blocks which is `table.shape[1]\\n`. So you can pass arguments like so:

```
table.reshape(table.shape[0], table.shape[1]\\n, n)
```

or even in a more simple way:

```
table.reshape(table.shape[0], -1, n)
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks @mathfux. One question though, how do you specify the first two dimensions in the reshape if I consider that my desired split `n` value is always my 3rd dim, e.g. `reshape(x, y, n)` and `reshape(x, y, n)` respectively for each case scenario? Btw the `numpyviz` seems quite cool, nice work.

Comment: @ttsesm I've noticed a typo in a name of third figure, hoing to correct and add some update. Arguments of `reshape(x, y, n)` corresponds to lengths of `axis0`, `axis1` and `axis2` in my diagrams.

Comment: so this means that they could be replaced with `reshape(table.shape[0], -1, n)`? I am asking so that to make it possible to generalize.

Comment: @ttsesm You're right. This is the same that I've posted in my updated answer.